# Создание многопользовательской браузерной игры

Tags: разработка-игр, браузер, фреймворк

нужна помощь.
Решил попробовать создать браузерную игру для нескольких человек, 2D шутер (просто для начала, как идея).
Не знаю с чего начать, какие фреймворки можно использовать, или что к чему, очень прошу дать совет какой-нибудь.
Извините, если написал криво, просто даже не понимаю что спросить)
Если конкретный вопрос задавать, то какие технологии мне нужно использовать?

Comment: Открываете интернет и гуглите как сделать игру, скорее всего вылезет что-то типо туториалов в Unity

Comment: Для начала надо натренировать базовые основы программирования. Написать небраузерную игру (хотя бы крестики-нолики), потом написать небраузерную многопользовательскую игру крестики-нолики. Отточив базовые основы, можно вернуться к вопросу фреймворков. Иначе Вы просто не увидите в них пользы. Не сможете эффективно использовать их сильные стороны.

Comment: Если простую браузерную: `canvas`, `websocket`, `expressjs`; но тут надо понимать, какой у вас уровень, вот что вы уже написали?

Comment: да, я делал игры на юнити. также програмирую на питоне, дс вообщем.